# Pose Recognition with TensorFlow

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to classify images of people by a specific pose using machine learning. The categories of images I'm collecting are "pose" or "unknown". I have plenty of photos of people in the pose as well as people not in the pose.

The model seems to be overfitting the "pose" category because when I focus the camera on anything other than a person, it also shows a confident score for "pose" rather than the "unknown" category. I'm wondering if I should include tons of photos of randomness in the "unknown" collection to help with this? And if I add tons of those photos, should I add an equal amount of the "pose" photos to not introduce a bias in the model?

In addition, I've considered using OpenCV to pre-process the images for contours before feeding into the ML model, any thoughts on this?

I'm following the [Tensorflow for Poets](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/index.html#0) tutorials if that helps. Thanks in advance for any tips!

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow for Poets link that you follow is not powerful enough and retraining it may cause the Over-fitting. Note that it uses a simple CNN with a softmax layer on top of the representation. You have to apply regulation to avoid over-fitting otherwise the bottleneck_tensor with input_depth = 3,  bottleneck_tensor_size = 2048, input_width = 299, input_height = 299 can be easily over-fitted. You can also use the deeper models and better pooling in your CNN. For details please check [the code](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2/blob/master/scripts/retrain.py).

Adding photos does not avoid bias in the ML model, AFAIK, OpenCV does not have any negative impact on your ML model.